# Why is the code body not giving the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code as follows displays the least commonly repeated number in the list and works correctly and gives me the answer 3...

```
    theList = [1,3,1,2,2]
listCheck, least = len(theList), 0
for theLeast in theList:
    if theList.count(theLeast) <= listCheck :
        listCheck = theList.count(theLeast)
        least = theLeast
print (least)
```

However when I define & change the list to a sequence of integers, the code says that 1 is the least common??

```
 def The_uncommon(integers):
    theList = integers
    listCheck, least = len(theList), 0
    for theLeast in theList:
        if theList.count(theLeast) <= listCheck :
            listCheck = theList.count(theLeast)
            least = theLeast
            return (least)
print(The_uncommon([1,3,1,2,2]))
```

Any advice is welcome

Comment: you `return (least)` right away so it has only checked 1

Comment: Thanks! Something so simple @depperm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classical indentation problem with python.

```
   def The_uncommon(integers):
        theList = integers
        listCheck, least = len(theList), 0
        for theLeast in theList:
            if theList.count(theLeast) <= listCheck :
                listCheck = theList.count(theLeast)
                least = theLeast
        return (least)
    print(The_uncommon([1,3,1,2,2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about your **indentation**. :)

In the first snippet, you are iterating through the entire loop, whereas in the second example where you define a function, you are returning the **first** `least` occurrence.

Comment: Thanks IMcoins, where would you recommend taking out the indentation? :)

Comment: I usually never give full answers to people I believe are beginning and struggling with basic programming concepts. I don't think I would make you a favor just giving right away the answer.

However, I gave you a nice hint that would guide you, and even teach you some terminology. :)